# Как сделать combobox на считку/запись 2-х байтов по смещению?

Tags: c#

Как в приложении сделать combobox на считку/запись 2-х байтов в "Hex" перевернутом по смещению 0x324 из файла. (Перевернутый Hex значит например: 300 десятичное в обычном Hex будет 01 2C, а в Hex перевернутом будет 2C 01).

Например: если выбрана 1-ая строка в combobox тогда нужна считка/запись в файл по смещению 0x324 значения 0x00. 
Если 10-ая строка, тогда считка/запись в файл значения 0x0A. 
Если 300-ая строка тогда считка/запись в файл 0x012C (точнее это нужно делать в перевернутом виде 0x2C01).
Считка/Запись нужно чтоб делались в буфере программы. А уже по нажатию кнопки Save произойдет запись в файл. (Считка происходит по нажатию кнопки Open, а запись происходит по кнопке Save). Кнопки считывающие и записывающие все байты, Open и Save уже написаны.

Comment: В чем проблема-то? Про "перевернутый" почитайте, кстати, про "endianness"...

Comment: Как тогда в коде прописать что если выбран трехсотый элемент, тогда записать по смещению 0x324 значение 2C 01 ?  'private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 299)
            {
               // записать значение 0x2C01 по смещению 0x324
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 300)
            {
                // записать значение 0x2D01 по смещению 0x324
            }'

Comment: if (elementNumber == 300){WriteWord(0x324, 0x012C);} - я бы начал, да и, пожалуй, закончил, таким кодом...